# upload .ipa file with multer in node express app

Tags: node.js, app-store-connect, mime-types, multer, ipa

I'm trying to upload a .ipa file to the server with node express app api with help of multer [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
package. But I don't know the exact mimetype of the ipa file for multer. If the mimetype is **application/octet-stream** then, how to use it in the multer package.

```js
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "application/octet-stream") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 250,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
```